# Model View Presenter and Composite Views

Tags: java, design-patterns, swing, mvp, passive-view

I'm trying to follow the MVP (specifically Passive-View) pattern in a java swing ui application.

The basic design of the application reminds a wizard control. The screen is divided to two main parts:

- an active view.
- a static navigation bar, with navigation buttons.

The user can use buttons to change the active view, but the bar is always displayed.

Modeling this scenario, I have a bunch of diffirent screers, each with it's own presenter, view interface and view implementation (using JPanel). Then I have a Shell presenter, view intefrace and view implementation, using a JFrame. The idea is that the shell will load first and always by displayed, showing the bottom navigation bar and leaving a space for the active view. The shell presenter will allow setting the current active screen, somewhat like this:

```
interface View {
}

class Presenter {
    View view;

    public Presenter(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public View getView() {
        return view;
    }

}

interface ShellView extends View {
    void setActiveView(View activeView);
}

class ShellPresenter extends Presenter {
    private ShellView shellView;

    public void setActivePresenter(Presenter activePresenter) { 
        shellView.setActiveView(activePresenter.getView());
    }
}

class ShellFrame implements ShellView {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel activePanel;
    private JPanel navigationBar;

    public ShellFrame() {
        Container c = frame.getContentPane();
        c.add(activePanel);
        c.add(navigationBar);
    }

    public setActiveView(View activeView) {
        ???
    }
}
```

The problem is in the setActiveView method: I'm not sure how to set the activeView to the activePanel, when the View interface is general and as such doens't know anything about JPanels. Obviously I wouldn't want my presenters to know about JPanels as well.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? None of these answers are particularly good. I just posted this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836421/how-dumb-can-mvp-views-really-be

Answer (score 1):

Could you modify the definition of View to:

```
interface View {
    JComponent getContainer();
}
```

So that each view can easily get the view contents?  The shell needn't know what implementation of JComponent is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Your View interface needs to provide some way to obtain something displayable in a JPanel:

```
interface View {
    Component getComponent();
}
```

Then in ShellFrame (assuming you use BorderLayout, as I would) you can set the view in the following way:

```
public setActiveView(View activeView) {
   activePanel.add(activeView.getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `JFrame` **is** the `View`, not each individual active sub-view. The view that is active right now is a rendering job, and therefore should be done by the `View`, not by the `Presenter`. Imagine you wanted to swap in a different `View` that instead of having only one subview visible, they were all visible, but the one that was active had a different background color. The presenter just controls which one is active, but the `View` controls what is meant by active.

So your task cannot be done without breaking encapsulation because you are trying to do a job that by it's very nature breaks encapsulation. So I would do something like this:

```
class PresenterManager {
    private Presenter activePresenter;
    private List<Presenter> allPresenters;

    IView view;

    PresenterManager(IView view) {
        this.view = view;
        view.subscribe(this);
    }

    void addPresenter(Presenter p) {
        allPresenters.add(p);
    }

    void setView(int index) {
        view.setView(index);
        activePresenter = allPresenters.get(index);
    }
}

class SwingView implements IView {
    List<SubView> allViews;
    SubView activeView;
    int lastIndex;

    public void setView(int index) {
        if(index != lastIndex) {
            activeView.setVisible(false);
            activeView = allViews.get(index);
            lastIndex = index;
        }
    }
}
```